# C++: serialization using sstream

Tags: c++, serialization, sstream

I am testing a serialization code below, which fails for a few numbers. Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
   std::stringstream ss;

   for (unsigned int m = 0; m < 101; ++m)
   {
      ss.clear();

      unsigned int t = m;

      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
      {
         unsigned char c = t;
         ss << c;
         t >>= 8;
      }

      unsigned int n = 0;

      for (unsigned int i = 0, j = 0; i < 4; ++i, j += 8)
      {
         unsigned char c;
         ss >> c;
         n = n | (c << j);
      }

      if (n != m)
         std::cout << "not working for " << m << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This is the results.

```
not working for 9
not working for 10
not working for 11
not working for 12
not working for 13
not working for 32
```

Comment: You are trying to perform binary serialization, but are using formatted input/output functions meant for text. The numbers that don't work happen to be ASCII codes of whitespace characters; `ss >> c` skips whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment and stare at the "non-working" values. If you stare at them, long enough, they will suddenly look very, very familiar.

You will note that all of them correspond to whitespace characters, in the ASCII table: NL, CR, FF, VT, and the most favorite character of mine: SP, the space character, ASCII code 32 (I think I missed one, I'm just too lazy to look it up...)

`>>`, on a stream, automatically discards all whitespace characters. If your goal is to read and write individual `char` values, to streams, you don't want to use `<<` and `>>`. You want to use `read()` and `write()` methods.

(well, you could probably use `<<`, but to be consistent, just use `read` and `write`).